# Comparing generic type T to Object

Tags: java, generics, interface, sortedset

I have the following class

`public class SkipListSet<T extends Comparable<T>> implements SortedSet<T> {`

I am using an internal wrapper class:

`class Node<T extends Comparable<T>> {`

Since I am implementing the `SortedSet` interface, I am starting to tackle the required classes.

Though, contains has Object as an argument, I wonder why I can't change this to T target. If I do I get the following error:

```
The method contains(T) of type SkipListSet<T> must override or implement a supertype method
```

```
    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object target) {
        
        ArrayList <Node<T>> lastNodeSeen = new ArrayList<Node<T>>();
        Node<T> current;

        // Start at top of header
        current = header.getLevel(maxHeight);
        
        while (current.nextNode.data != target) {

            // No reference to other node
            if (current.nextNode == null) {
                // retreat is not an option, we must dig deeper
                if (current.prevNode == null)
                {
                    current = current.getLevel(current.getHeight() - 1);
                }
                // we must retreat
                current = current.prevNode;
            }
            // If 
            else if (current.nextNode.data.compareTo(target) > 0) { // if data > target, then 1
                
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 1):

The [`SortedSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) interface extends the [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) interface, which defines the method [`contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) like so:

```
boolean contains(Object o);
```

The parameter is explicitly specified to be an Object, which is why you can't change it to `T` when overriding it.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out a way to solve this problem is by typecasting Object target.

Like so:

T newTarget = (T)(target);

You'll get the following warning:

```
Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to T
```

But for my purposes I don't mind it.

Comment: If it solved your problem, you can accept your own answer